# Addon Domain Images NOT LOADING Htaccess Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, cpanel, addon-domain

Im having problem with my addon domain, on my primary domain everything works fine, I have the wordpress installed and running perfectly using the following htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?addon-domain\.com
Rewriterule .* - [L]
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

On addon domain subfolder It's working and loading site like an individual domain as I wish it to be but images are not loading, the following addon domain htaccess file:

```
Options -MultiViews -Indexes +FollowSymlinks
<IfModule mod_security.c>
    SecFilterEngine Off
    SecFilterScanPOST Off
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript text/css text/html text/xml
</IfModule>

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^addon\-domain\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.addon\-domain\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/domain\.com\/addon\-domain\.com" [R=301,L]
```

Now... I tried hotlink disabled, enabled with rules for each domain and addon, not deal... tried removing domain htaccess and nothing happeans.

Im running a videoscript in addon domain and thumbnails for videos works fine, when I upload images it's loading normally, but all css images and subfolders images like logo arent. :-(

I can access css, js and other templates files using direct address but no one single image file opens... on firefox i got this error message:

```
The image "http://addon-domain.com/templates/frontend/default/images/videozoom.png" cannot be displayed because it contain errors.
```

And all other images in different folders display same message... I have only Htacces file on root domain and addondomain folder.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

just add your site to hotlink protection and everything will work fine =D